# Pipe: How to create N Pipes?

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, io-redirection

I'm trying to create a shell and I'm having trouble when implementing the pipes. The goal is to type commands on the shell that's created  (e.g. `ls -l -a | sort -u < myfile > myfile2 | w`) . The number of pipes is random and the code has to support n pipes.

I have something like this:

```
int fork_pipe(int n)
{

int i;
int in=0;
int fd[2];

for(i=0; i< n; i++)
{
    pipe(fd);

    if(fork()==0)
    {

        if(in != 0)
        {
            dup2(in,0);
            close(in);
        }

        if(out != 1)
        {
            dup2(out,1)
            close(out);
        }

        execpv(argv_current_command,argv_current_command++); //Incompleto

        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }

}

if(in!=0)
{
    dup2(in,0);
}

execpv(argv_current_command,argv_current_command++);

}
```

and I have a pipe_count to know the number of pipes that will later be send to the fork_pipe function as n.

Comment: The answer to the question as posed is simply that you call `pipe()` once for each pipe you want to create.  I suspect you're really hoping for a complete implementation of the function you've conceived, but that's unlikely to be forthcoming.  Consider looking through the *many* prior questions posed here about piping, forking, and programmatically creating pipelines -- very likely their answers will provide some guidance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i have read many questions and answers but none of them seem to fit what i want. Normaly , the commands are already in the main but mine come from the keyboard.

Comment: As I said, the answer to the question as posed is that you create multiple pipes by calling `pipe()` multiple times.  It seems likely that you already knew or could have assumed that.  If you want an answer directed at your specific point(s) of confusion, then pose a question directed at those particular points.

Comment: `execpv` doesn't return, unless there was an error. So `close(fd[1]); in = fd[0];` never get a chance to run. You need to add an `else` part to `if fork`. Also, you don't `fork` for the last program you want to execute, why?